# Add event to iframe body

Tags: jquery, iframe, events

I am setting up a own made wysiwyg plugin for jQuery. He is almost finished but know i want to add a keyup event to a iframe with designmode on. But i can't get it worked. I tryied almost everything a found on the internet. The class of the wysiwyg iframe with designmode is .dhwysiwyg. I though the next code will work:

```
$(function () {
$('.dhwysiwyg', container).keyup(function () {
// the script
});
});
```

But this won't work. The keyup event don't exists.

Can someone help me?

Tom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the page in your iframe load its own copy of jQuery? If so, try this in your *outer* page (the page with the iframe in it, not the page **in** the iframe):

```
$(function() {
  var frameWindow = $('.dhwysiwyg').get(0).contentWindow;
  frameWindow.$('body').keyup(function() {
    // handler
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the particulars of your example, but I know that pushing events to an iFrame will sometimes violate the security policy of your browser.

Answer (score 0):

I've never heard of this "design mode" thing (only contentEditable) but your problem might be a security limitation. What are the iframe contents, and are they on the same domain?

Answer (score -1):

this method work for me

```
$(function() {
      var frameWindow = $('.dhwysiwyg').get(0).contentWindow;
      $(frameWindow.document).delegate("body",'keyup',function() {
      var bodycontent=$(frameWindow.document.body).text();
    });
});
```